# How to use @ServerRequestFilter in the quarkus framework that uses vert.x to read the request body inside ContainerRequestContext

Tags: vert.x, quarkus

I want to print json logs for the body of the post request in the @ServerRequestFilter filter

```
    @ServerRequestFilter
public void requestFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    InputStream entityStream = requestContext.getEntityStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int r;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((r = entityStream.read(data)) > 0) {
        out.write(data, 0, r);
    }
    log.info(StrUtil.format("body->[{}]", out.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    requestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
}
```

But I found that whatever I do to the entityStream triggers:

```
java.io.IOException: Attempting a blocking read on io thread
   at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.VertxInputStream$VertxBlockingInput.readBlocking
```

The reason seems to be that InputStream is a blocking IO, but VertX requires a non-blocking IO.

So I would like to ask **how to read the body of the request in the filter in a non-blocking way**

Please don't let me print the request log in the **interceptor**, I know I can do that, but I still want to know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you should add `@Blocking` on a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, like so:

```
@Blocking 
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

Comment: But won't this make the whole project blocking? The reason I use vertx is to make the project responsive and non-blocking

Comment: If you want it to be non-blocking, you shouldn't be reading the whole request body in the filter